# How come maven build fails but I can successfully deploy my application to Glassfish and run it?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish

Perhaps this is a very simple question but I am confused.

I am using IntelliJ and I created a very simple Java Web application.

When I run comman

```
mvn clean install
```

on command line, or on IntelliJ I get:

> C:\Development\sakila\web\src\main\java\com\tugay\sakilaweb\pages\BasePage.java:[19,1]
>   annotations are not supported in -source 1.3 (use -source 5 or higher
>   to enable annotations) @Named
>
> C:\Development\sakila\web\src\main\java\com\tugay\sakilaweb\userprops\LoggedInUser.java:[15,1]
>   annotations are not supported in -source 1.3 (use -source 5 or higher
>   to enable annotations) @SessionScoped

But when I simply choose to deploy my application to Glassfish, application runs just fine..

I am confused, does not IntelliJ first call install to build the war file, then deploy it to Glassfish?

How come clean install fails, but deploying it to Glassfish works?

Correct the tags of the question please if required..

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA + Maven what is the need for dependency entries in an iml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004443/intellij-idea-maven-what-is-the-need-for-dependency-entries-in-an-iml-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All IDEs have their own internal compiler, so that a change to any source file will trigger a recompile.
Since you're calling 'clean' a full recompile is done by Maven. Without the clean there are probably no changes, since the IDE has already compiled those adjustments. However, in the end, you'd like to be able to do a 'clean deploy' so be sure your project is configured correctly.
In this case it seems like your maven-compiler-plugin isn't configured correctly, please adjust the [source and target](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: How does the IDE compile the code with its own compiler, and get the jars from maven directory I have ( the .m2 directory? ) I thought when you did maven install, it will know where the dependencies are, but how can the IDE know?

Comment: IDE parses Maven file and gets the dependencies from Maven, but uses its own compiler and the project model. Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004694/104891) for more details.