# Multiple ways of declaring dependencies in Maven IntelliJ projects

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

In new Maven projects in IntelliJ, I see 2 ways of declaring new dependencies:

1. Manually editing the pom.xml file, adding a `<dependency/>` declaration.
   This automatically (maven auto-import is on) adds `Maven: ...` entries to the project .iml file and all is well.
2. Using the `File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies` menu. This **only** creates entries in the .iml file.

This seems like unwanted behavior. IntelliJ doesn't overwrite the .iml file when importing the pom.xml Maven file, but *merges* dependencies from the pom.xml and additionally-defined ones from the .iml.

I want to enforce a single way of adding dependencies in my team (using pom.xml only, for external mvn builds), and the ability to bypass the pom.xml and directly add dependencies to the .iml creates the illusion of a valid build (when in fact, it is not).

Am I missing something? How can I enforce one way of adding dependencies? Is there a way through which IntelliJ will add dependencies to the pom.xml file instead of the .iml files?

### EDIT

In this question ([IntelliJ IDEA + Maven what is the need for dependency entries in an iml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004443/intellij-idea-maven-what-is-the-need-for-dependency-entries-in-an-iml-file)) it is claimed that

> This can be also used to experiment with dependencies without changing the pom.xml. Note that all the modifications you make will be reverted on next Maven import.

But this is not the behavior I see. The .iml file doesn't get reverted, but merged.

Comment: Why do you consider .iml files ? If your project needs to be compiled across all the IDE then whats the case ? Never depend on .iml which is IDE specific. My suggestion would be add in pom.xml which will make it to work irrespective of the IDE you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) environment.

This won't stop your team members adding dependencies in the wrong place, but it will ensure that is caught very early and flag it up that they need to add it to your pom, then it just comes down to education.

Answer (score 0):

`Pom.xml` is only to be used by Maven, IntelliJ does pick up the dependencies from the `pom.xml` if you have configured your IDE properly. If you however, want to use maven solely, you can add the jars to your local maven repo and then call them from your `pom.xml` normally via the `<dependency>` tag.

You can learn how to add local jars [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).